# Validate tkinter user input, presence check

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to validate user inputs on a tkinter GUI. I will need to have a presence check, a format check(a date) and one of the inputs can only be one of 3 options and I am not sure how to do these. I have looked at other examples but they are hard to understand because I have not been using classes. Does anybody know how to do this?

Here is some example code

```
Entry1= Entry(window, bg="Blue", fg="white",font="40")
Entry2= Entry(window, bg="Blue", fg="white",font="40")
Entry3= Entry(winodw, bg="Blue", fg="white",font="40")


#Assigning the input boxes to area on the screen
Entry1.grid(row=1, column=1)
Entry2.grid(row=2, column=1)
Entry3.grid(row=3, column=1)

forename=Entry1.get()
surname=Entry2.get()
dateofbirth=Entry3.get()
```

Comment: for the three options, can't you use `contextMenu`

Comment: are you wanting to do the validation as the user types, or do the validation after the user clicks a button (eg: a "submit" button or "OK" button)?

Comment: there is a submit button that i have created but i havent included it on the example code.

Answer (score 0):

You need a validate `function` that checks the string variable of the three `Entry` fields, ie:

```
def validate():
    if forename == valid_forename:
        print 'Valid forename'
    else:
        print '%s is not a valid forename' % forename
```

And you can call this from a [Button](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm):

```
vButton = Button(window, text='Validate', command=validate)
vButton.grid()
```

Your three types of 'checks' will go into the `validate()` function. You should be able to accomplish these with some simple value checking, but if you can't, you should post a specific question about the type of value checking you can't get to work and what you tried to make it work.

Comment: This solution doesn't make sense. Your `validate` function returns `True` or `False`, but nothing will use those values. When you call a function from a button, anything that function returns is simply ignored.

Comment: It's just an example. I don't have enough information to make a proper validate function, I was leaving that to the OP. I'll edit it though

Answer (score -2):

Creating a GUI/Tkinter class and calling it is a bit different from ordinary Pythonclasses so below is an example with an entry box. Note that to open the GUI window you have to call  root.mainloop() # run

```
from Tkinter import *

import Tkinter as tk


class Application(Frame):

    """ a GUI/tkinter class application"""
    def __init__(self, root):

        Frame.__init__(self)



        self.pack()

        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):

        # Create a label

        self.label = Label(self, text= "Type text here!")
        self.label.pack( side='top', anchor='n', fill='x', expand=False,padx=1, pady=1 )

        # Create an Entry - box where the text is typed in.
        self.text_entry = Entry(self)
        self.text_entry.pack( side='top', anchor='n', fill='x', expand=True,padx=4, pady=4)





        # Create a textbox

        self.box_txt = tk.Text(self, width = 65, height = 25, wrap = WORD)
        self.box_txt.pack(side=BOTTOM)


         # Create a submit button
        self.button = Button(self, text = "Submit!", command = self.display_text_in_listbox)
        self.button.pack( side='right', anchor='w', fill='x', expand=False,padx=1, pady=1 )





  # Method for getting the text from the entry box and displaying it
  # in the listbox

    def display_text_in_listbox(self):
        msg = self.text_entry.get() # get text from entry

        self.box_txt.delete(0.0, END)  # Clear the listbox from current text

        self.box_txt.insert(0.0, msg) # Add text written into entry


root = tk.Tk() # Instantiate tk - inter class object
root.title("My TKinter application") # Text on top of the window

root.geometry("900x700")  # the size of the window, height * width

app = Application(root)  # Instantiate root in Application class
root.mainloop() # run
```

Comment: why does your answer have text widgets in it, and why do your comments call it a listbox? The question is about doing validation on an Entry widget.

Comment: Because in order to use the Entry widget you would have to call it with mainloop(), but perhaps the OP has defined that elsewhere. The entry content, in validate() could be done as in display_text_in_listbox() wherein msg = self.text_entry.get()  gets the content to be compared and displayed, as the OP wants with forename=Entry1.get().